# How do I create different txt.name in other execute

Tags: python

```
i = 1
while i <=10:

    f = open("txtfile.txt",+str(i) "a+")

    f.write("111\n")
    f.write("222\n")
    i = i + 1
    f.close()
```

I want to create txt in many times , But the top code is not in my mind.

I want to create a txt.file1 , and if it exist , the next time execute name is txt.file2.

Comment: Please explain with more clarity what do you want, it's not clear

Comment: Create a txt file in folder , when folder exists , I want the txt name is not same .(create other txt file)  So it can txt1 , txt2 , txt3 in folder

Comment: try using ```sys``` to check file's contain

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to create 10 files in Python 3.6+, named from `file.txt01` to `file.txt10`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

for i in range(1, 11):
    f = Path(f'file.txt{i:02d}')
    f.write_text('111\n222\n')
```

If you want to create a new file on every run, sequentially numbered ad infinitum, do this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

i = 1

while True:
    if Path(f'file.txt{i}').exists():
        i += 1
    else:
        Path(f'file.txt{i}').write_text('111\n222\n')
        break
```

But that is very inefficient though.

So maybe this is a better solution:

```py
from pathlib import Path

source = Path('/home/accdias/temp')
prefix = 'file.txt'
slots = set([int(_.name.replace(prefix, '')) for _ in source.glob(f'{prefix}*')])
slot = min(set(range(1, max(slots, default=1) + 1)) - slots, default=max(slots, default=1) + 1)
filename = source / f'{prefix}{slot}'
filename.write_text('111\n222\n')
```

The solution above is nice because it take into account any gaps that may exist and pick the next lowest slot number available.

Comment: nah, he want to create one file for each time execute, and preventing name to be same, not creating 10 at the time.

Comment: @WhereisourMonica, the code posted doesn't show that. The `while` loop shows the contrary. But the question is not clear anyway. He needs to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, on every run new file (txtfileNN.txt) with incremented number need to be created ( NN is one or two digit number), try below code:

```
import os
import re

file_base_name = 'txtfile'
r = re.compile(file_base_name+'\d{0,2}.txt')
all_files_in_dir=sorted([i for i in os.listdir() if r.match(i)])
print('Existing files in directory: {}'.format(all_files_in_dir))
# Existing files in directory: ['txtfile.txt', 'txtfile1.txt', 'txtfile10.txt']

if not all_files_in_dir:
    # File does not exist yet
    out_file = file_base_name + '.txt'
else:
    highest_file=all_files_in_dir[-1]
    # 'txtfile10.txt'
    int_portion = highest_file.replace('.txt', '').split(file_base_name)[-1]
    if not int_portion:
        # no integer in file, so it it txtfile.txt
        next_int = 1
    else:
        next_int = int(int_portion) + 1

    out_file = file_base_name + str(next_int) + '.txt'
print('Next file name : {}'.format(out_file))
# Next file name : txtfile11.txt

# Now write text in new file    
f = open(out_file, 'a')
f.write("111\n")
f.write("222\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: How can I use this code to create over txtfile10.txt ? @Nasimuddin Ansari

Comment: @Lu儒 I did not get your question. Please elaborate it.

Comment: Your code can create txtfile2 , when txtfile1 exists, but it only can create until txtfile10 , if I want create txtfile11 , Is it possible?   Thanks!! @Nasimuddin Ansari

Comment: if txtfile11 is highest numbered file, it will create txtfile12. if txtfile14 is highest numbered file, next file will be txtfile15 and so on ... please tweak code as per your need

Comment: Hi I can create over 10 txtfile ,  but can you tell me your code in line '\d{0,2} diffenent in '\d{2} when I use '\d{2} , I can create over txtfile10. Thanks  @Nasimuddin Ansari

Comment: ```\d{0,2}``` regex means - number of digits may from 0 or 1 or max 2. ```\d{2}``` regex means - always 2 digit (10 to 99)

Comment: Thank you very much. I wonder why {0,3} can't create txtfile0~txtfile100. When I want to create txtfile0~txtfile100 it need to use {0,2} then I can use {3} to create txtfile10~txtfile100.  @Nasimuddin Ansari